# Delphi SOAP service - issues with multiple connections to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, delphi, soap, connection

I have an issue with Oracle Database connection via Delphi SOAP. When one connection with callouts to the database is established, everything works fine - the issue occurs when another callout is made by another client (i. e. via another socket) - the first callout/operation is canceled and the database itself freezes. The error message is ORA-03013: user requested cancel of current operation. Error only occurs if an operation is performed, if there are multiple connections but only one uses the database, everything is fine.

This is the first time I am facing such difficulties.

I am able to open 1024 sockets and I expect that all of them can call the database and perform operations on it without terminating any ongoing connection or freezing the system. Currently only one client can perform operations on the database.

Comment: Often it is a timeout due to locks. If they are all trying to lock the same thing they will end up waiting on each other which means the clients will sit waiting until the timeout expires and they cancel the operation.

Comment: But this is not the case, as the entire thing is still not released and those are the tests that we are performing on it internally. It all simply fails as soon as a second callout to the database is made, nothing is cancelled manually, everything happens by itself. Operation is in progress → second connection with a callout to the database is made → first connection is terminated → database freezes and the error ORA-03013 appears in the logfile.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question and show us what an *Oracle Database connection via Delphi SOAP* looks like.